# Right way to build API for web page

Tags: php, api, symfony

I am using symfony. When I am creating web page that will also have an API how should I do It ? Difference between them is that API will return for example JSON string as response, but web page will return html/text response if I am not mistaken. So should I add some condition that if the URL will be `api.something.com` then return JSON and if it will be `something.com` then return html/text ?  Or should I build separate controllers ? but they will be same with exception of returning object.

Comment: Try to use FOSRestBundle and NelmioApiDocBundle. It brings everything you need to build a REST API with documentation in a efficient way. There is a lot of documentation available http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Best practices

It is better to separate domains, this way you can use RESTful best practices to build your API without interfering with your www urls. The security checks are different for an API than for a web request, it means that you need to build separate controllers as well to handle those checks properly.

## For small projects

If you really want to use one controller for both usage (because you don't think your projet need to have the higher standards) you can check for a header in the request to distinguish an api call from a web request. For instance you could use the header `accept: application/json` for your api request.

#### Example:

```
function isXmlHttpRequest()
{
    return !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest';
}
function isApiRequest()
{
    return strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) === 'application/json';
}
if(isApiRequest() || isXmlHttpRequest()){
    return $jsonResponse;
}else{
    return $webPage;
}
```

## Framework suggestion

[Laravel framework](https://laravel.com/) is a good solution to make such web architecture. It helps you to separate domains and controllers in a simple and easy way. It has tools to help you build a RESTful architecture as well in no time. You can learn how to use it [here](https://laracasts.com/).

Comment: Thanks, that was good explanation I think I understand it a bit more now. The main problem is just question "What is best?" becuase I have only created small pages for learning and when I want to do something like this, then both approaches (eg. separate API controllers vs one controller) work, but one approach is better then the other one and without experiences it's hard to tell which one.

Comment: I am glad to hear it. I would say always follow the good practices, no matter what your project size is. It will then become an habit and make your code understandable for other dev and make it easy to maintain. So even though both approaches work, the better approach is the one that allows any developer to take over your project without having to explain it to him and allows you to add specific code for the api side (or web side) without breaking anything or having complex code in your controllers.

Comment: He was saying that he currently uses Symfony. Why introduce a other framework here if Symfony would work well with FOSRestBundle for instance?

Comment: As I said it is a suggestion, plus Laravel uses some part of Symphony. But I would be pleased if other people introduce me to frameworks that I don't know that could help me do what I am trying to do. So I am just sharing knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with multiple ways.

1) if you're app has big traffic, then go with api.example.com. a new domain with probably new hosting.

2) you can use same domain. Like www.example.com/api/create/foo.

In both case make sure you have different controller and methods.

You are good to go..

Comment: But why different controllers ? They will same except for the last part where API controller will return `json` and web controller will create view or something.

Comment: If you wish you can go with same controller. This because of code readability.if new developer comes to your project it makes easy to understand the code